# Error in Lisp: The LET binding spec is malformed

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, clisp

I'm really new to common Lisp and having some struggles. I'm working on a function that given **x**, **y** and an **array** with the index for vertical value returns **NIL** if there's any element diagonal from (x y).

```
(defun diagonal? (x y array)
    (loop for line from 0 to 19 do
        (let (col (aref array line)) (
            (if (= col -1) (return-from diagonal? t))
            (let (diag (= (abs (- x line)) (abs (- y col)))) (
                if (= diag T) (return-from diagonal? NIL))
            )
    )))
    return T
)
```

When I try this function however, I get the following error:

```
; caught ERROR:
;   The LET binding spec (AREF ARRAY LINE) is malformed.

;     (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA DIAGONAL?
;         (X Y ARRAY)
;       (BLOCK DIAGONAL?
;         (LOOP FOR LINE FROM 0 TO 19
;               DO (LET (COL #)
;                    (# #)))
;         RETURN
;         T))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First and extremely important: use automatic indentation.

```
(defun diagonal? (x y array)
  (loop for line from 0 to 19 do
        (let (col (aref array line)) (
                                      (if (= col -1) (return-from diagonal? t))
                                      (let (diag (= (abs (- x line)) (abs (- y col)))) (
                                                                                        if (= diag T) (return-from diagonal? NIL))
                                        )
                                      )))
  return T
  )
```

Then your code looks strange with long lines: never put parentheses on their own line and never end a line with an open parenthesis.

Improved:

```
(defun diagonal? (x y array)
  (loop for line from 0 to 19 do
        (let (col (aref array line))
          ((if (= col -1)
               (return-from diagonal? t))
           (let (diag (= (abs (- x line))
                         (abs (- y col))))
             (if (= diag T)
                 (return-from diagonal? NIL))))))
  return T)
```

Second: `LET` expects a list of bindings. A single binding is a variable or `(variable value)`:

```
(defun diagonal? (x y array)
  (loop for line from 0 to 19 do
        (let ((col (aref array line)))
          ((if (= col -1)
               (return-from diagonal? t))
           (let ((diag (= (abs (- x line))
                          (abs (- y col)))))
             (if (= diag T)
                 (return-from diagonal? NIL))))))
  return T)
```

Third: LET expects a body of Lisp forms. That is zero or more Lisp forms:

```
(defun diagonal? (x y array)
  (loop for line from 0 to 19 do
        (let ((col (aref array line)))
          (if (= col -1)
               (return-from diagonal? t))
          (let ((diag (= (abs (- x line))
                         (abs (- y col)))))
            (if (= diag T)
                (return-from diagonal? NIL)))))
  return T)
```

Fourth: `=` expects numbers as arguments. `T` is not a number. `=` already returns `T` or `NIL` which we can test.

```
(defun diagonal? (x y array)
  (loop for line from 0 to 19 do
        (let ((col (aref array line)))
          (if (= col -1)
              (return-from diagonal? t))
          (if (= (abs (- x line))
                 (abs (- y col)))
              (return-from diagonal? NIL))))
  return T)
```

Fifth: `return T` is not a valid Lisp form. We can just return `T` directly.

```
(defun diagonal? (x y array)
  (loop for line from 0 to 19 do
        (let ((col (aref array line)))
          (if (= col -1)
              (return-from diagonal? t))
          (if (= (abs (- x line))
                 (abs (- y col)))
              (return-from diagonal? NIL))))
  T)
```

Sixth: we don't need the `LET` for `col`, we can replace it with another `FOR` in the `LOOP`.

```
(defun diagonal? (x y array)
  (loop for line from 0 to 19
        for col = (aref array line)
        do
        (if (= col -1)
            (return-from diagonal? t))
        (if (= (abs (- x line))
               (abs (- y col)))
            (return-from diagonal? NIL))))
  T)
```

Seventh: multiple `IF` can be written as a single `COND`.

```
(defun diagonal? (x y array)
  (loop for line from 0 to 19
        for col = (aref array line)
        do (cond ((= col -1)
                  (return-from diagonal? t))
                 ((= (abs (- x line))
                     (abs (- y col)))
                  (return-from diagonal? nil))))
  t)
```

Eigth: `for from 0 to n` can be replaced by `below (+ n 1)` or `upto n`

```
(defun diagonal? (x y array)
  (loop for line below 20
        for col = (aref array line)
        do (cond ((= col -1)
                  (return-from diagonal? t))
                 ((= (abs (- x line))
                     (abs (- y col)))
                  (return-from diagonal? nil))))
  t)
```

Ninth: since `(RETURN-FROM ... T)` returns from a function which returns `T` explicitly by default, we can replace it with an `UNTIL` clause in the loop:

```
(defun diagonal? (x y array)
  (loop for line below 20
        for col = (aref array line)
        until (= col -1)
        when (= (abs (- x line))
                (abs (- y col)))
        do (return-from diagonal? nil))
  t)
```

Tenth: since col is just the iterating the values of the array:

```
(defun diagonal? (x y array)
  (loop for line below 20
        for col across array
        until (= col -1)
        when (= (abs (- x line))
                (abs (- y col)))
        do (return-from diagonal? nil))
  t)
```

Eleventh: suggestion by @Coredump, use `NEVER`. The default return value of the `LOOP` is now `T`. Return only then `nil`, when the `never` clause fails.

```
(defun diagonal? (x y array)
  (loop for line below 20
        for col across array
        until (= col -1)
        never (= (abs (- x line))
                 (abs (- y col)))))
```

Comment: eleventh? use "never" and not "return-from"?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/s_let_l.htm) a `let` has the following structure:

```
(let (var  (var2 expression))
  body ...)
```

Here the first binding has no value, but it is the same as writing:

```
(let ((var nil) (var2 expression))
  body ...)
```

Your bindings look like this:

```
(let (col                  ; col initialized to nil OK
     (aref array line))    ; variable aref initialized to?
 ...)
```

Your variable `aref` should only have one expression. In fact it seems you are lacking a set of parentesis making it look a little like Clojure. Perhaps it should have been:

```
(let ((col (aref array line)))
  ...)
```

Also I notice you have a `(` on the same line as if you are making a block. That won't work since `((if ....))` is not valid Common Lisp code. You get the error that operator should be a named function or a lambda. `let` is a block so the start `(let ...)` makes a block so you can have numerous expressions inside without extra parentheses.